# Unable to create SGX enclave in hardware mode - "invalid launch token" even though documentation specifies an invalid launch token as the first one

Tags: c++, intel, sgx

Intel's documentation says [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/709072) that if there is no previous launch token, an "invalid" token with all zeros should be used. This works perfectly in simulation mode, but in hardware mode it returns SGX_ERROR_INVALID_LAUNCH_TOKEN, even though that is exactly what it is asking for.

```
    // Initialize an "invalid" first token, as the documentation specifies (all zeros)
    sgx_launch_token_t token = {0};

    // Create enclave
    sgx_enclave_id_t id;
    int updated = 0;
    const auto status = sgx_create_enclave("enclave.signed.so", SGX_DEBUG_FLAG, &token, &updated, &id, NULL);

    if (status != SGX_SUCCESS) {
        throw "Failed to initialize enclave. (" + get_error_message(status) + ")";
    }
```

The code returns status = SGX_ERROR_INVALID_LAUNCH_TOKEN

```
Failed to initialize enclave. (The launch token is not correct.)
```

Is there maybe anything I'm missing from the building process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by my application using `libsgx_urts.so` from `/usr/lib` and `libsgx_uae_service.so` from the installation path of my SGX SDK (`/opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64` in my case.)

I changed the linking to the following:

`Simulation mode:
libsgx_urts.so => /opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/libsgx_urts.so
libsgx_uae_service.so => /opt/intel/sgxsdk/lib64/libsgx_uae_service.so`

`Hardware mode:
libsgx_urts.so => /usr/lib/libsgx_urts.so
libsgx_uae_service.so => /usr/lib/libsgx_uae_service.so`
`